# How to put license files into deployed react project?

Tags: reactjs, build

I am working on a react project in which I am using some open source libraries that I have to mention according to the license agreement.  It seems to me that these disappear in the built version. How can I make the license files visible in the deployed version?

Answer (score 0):

Place them in LICENSE.md in the root of your project, not in the dist/build folder. Refer to this [GitHub guide on determining a location for your license](https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/licensing-a-repository#determining-the-location-of-your-license) for more info.

Comment: I have tried that. But I can't find the license file when I look at the project files under 'Sources' in the developer tools in Chrome. You should be able to find the file there, right?

Comment: No, the license files won't be visible there or anywhere else on your actual website. If that's what you need then perhaps put them in a static folder. It's hard to provide an exact recommendation without more details about what you mean by 'I am using some open source libraries that I have to mention', what format the licenses are in, etc.

Comment: The licensing information is inside a txt file. And this txt-file has to be part of the files which get sent to the browser of the user of the web app.
Therefore, I think that a static folder is a good idea. But how do I create such a folder for the deployed version of the web app?

Comment: Perhaps this may help - https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/